# joins with subqueries or recursion?

Tags: sql, join, recursion, db2, subquery

I've tried a number of approaches on this one but just can't get to the correct result set.
I'm loath to revert to handling this in code & making multiple queries because I feel there is a reasonably simple solution there somewhere.

2 tables which contain process information.

process:

```
ID (key)
PARENT_ID
ROOT_ID
```

processdata

```
ID (key)
PROCESS_ID (key in process)
type
col1        
col2
```

My data is something like this;

process

```
id, root_id, parent_id
100, 1, 10
101, 1, 10
102, 1, 10
10, 1,  1
```

processdata

```
id,process_id,type,col1, col2
201,100,X,NULL,NULL
202,100,X,NULL,NULL
203,100,TYPE1,My Data for Type1,NULL
301,100,X,NULL,NULL
302,100,X,NULL,NULL
303,100,TYPE1,My Data for Type1,NULL
401,100,X,NULL,NULL
402,100,X,NULL,NULL
403,100,TYPE1,My Data for Type1,NULL
503,10,X,NULL,NULL
503,10,TYPE2,NULL,My data for type2
```

desired result

```
root_id,parent_id,process_id,col1,col2
1,100,203,My data for type1,My data for type2
1,101,303,My data for type1,My data for type2
1,102,403,My data for type1,My data for type2
```

you can view this as a hierarchy of processes;

```
ROOT PROCESS
TOP_LEVEL PROCESS type=TYPE2 (has a label that applies to all it's children)
    (it's possible that between the type1 and type2 header above there is another process_id -> parent_id iteration needed - can ignore for now)
    PROCESS type=type1  (has data about this instance of the process)
    PROCESS type=type1  (has data about this instance of the process)
    PROCESS type=type1  (has data about this instance of the process)

TOP_LEVEL PROCESS type=TYPE2 (has a label that applies to all it's children)
    PROCESS type=type1  (has data about this instance of the process)
    PROCESS type=type1  (has data about this instance of the process)
    PROCESS type=type1  (has data about this instance of the process)
```

The closest I have got is;

```
with processes as (     -- this gets me all the process_id's for the root process - there will be lots of these with different types
                select  id
                        ,parent_id
                from process as p 
                where root_process_id='1'
), processdatainfo as (             -- this should get the type 1 child processes
        select  pd.id
                ,pd.process_id
                ,col1
        from processdata as pd 
        where pd.process_id in ( select id from processes )
        and pd.type = 'TYPE1'
), parentprocesses as (             -- this should get the type 2 parents that have the label for the children
        select  process_id
                ,col2
        from db2inst1.processlog
        where process_id in ( select id from processes )
        and type = 'TYPE2'
)
select *                            -- and the magic.....well doesn't happen....
from processes 
    inner join processdatainfo 
        on (processes.id = processdatainfo.process_id)
    left join parentprocesses
        on (parentprocesses.process_id = processes.parent_id)
```

In my results col2 is always NULL
I do only get the 3 rows I expected though this is one thing I guess.
I've been back and forward with nested select's using subqueries, but this approach seems closest.
I've looked at recursive queries but this problem didn't seem to fit because although I do need to process up the tree I need to get one row for the results rather than a row for each recursion.

Also recursion looked difficult - it would need to stop recursing when it reaches the type2 process rather than all the way to the root_id
I can't use stored procedures because I'm not able to update the server in this case - my application is a client to it.

Although the tables are huge - between 60M and 140M rows, filtering on the root process ID drops the list of process_id's down to 10-20 which is why I thought the above WITH would help.

What I think I need is;

- list of process_id's for my root process. That limits the result set
  get my list of type1's and their parentid's
- from that, get the list of type2's where the parentid is the processid for the type2 record

Sounds so easy like that....

Comment: looks like sql server?

Comment: sorry - should have said - DB2

Comment: Problem underspecified.  Showing the desired result for one single particular case is a very bad way of providing specs.  Suggest your try and write down the ***reason*** why each of those rows in your "desired result" are expected to be there.

Comment: `root_process_id` invalid column

Comment: i was going to use sql server to test it http://rextester.com/HZUQZ47999

Comment: this code does not come close to working so I have no idea how you could have tested it.  root_process_id -- IN THE FIRST QUERY does not exist in your example model.   Also, are you really storing IDs as character strings?  Don't think so.  Please edit your example to be correct.